# Why use \" in arduino code?

Tags: string, data-type

While working with JSON parsing I noticed that the char type data string is written like this:

```
char json[] = "{\"sensor\":\"gps\",\"time\":1351824120,\"data\":[48.756080,2.302038]}";
```

Why there are (escapes) " ---" used in the code? Why can't we use the string normally?

Comment: Try it without and see what happens ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why there are (escapes) " ---" used in the code? Why can't we use the string normally?

Because escapes are required.

In C `"` means 'The start or end of a string', but `\"` means 'A double-quote character'.

There has to be a way to distinguish a double-quote character from a string delimiter so the compiler knows which is which. Without escapes your string would look like:

```cpp
char json[] = "{"sensor":"gps","time":1351824120,"data":[48.756080,2.302038]}";
```

and the compiler would find the end of the string at the second `"`, and then a load of junk before it finds the end-of-statement `;` character. It can't work out what `sensor":"gps","time":1351824120,"data":[48.756080,2.302038]}"` is supposed to be, since it isn't in the string, but after it.